# How many times can x unique values be pulled from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values (non unique) and I need to work out how many times I can pull out x (e.g 3) unique items from that array.

e.g.

```
[5, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 5]
```

What is the largest quantity of unique items of length 3 (e.g. `[5, 4, 1]`) I can retrieve?

For context, this is for an offer system in a shopping cart. The array of values is the product ids, and I need to know how many times I can apply a specific offer that requires 3 different items from the array of ids in order to be valid.

Thanks for any help - just ask if anything is unclear and I'll try to explain. If I've missed an existing question that answers this please let me know and I'll close this question.

Comment: All I would like to know is where the problem lies? What did you try so far and what is not working?[MCVE]

Comment: try array_unique function

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: And why `[5,4,1]`? And not `[5,3,2]` or `[5,4,2]`?

Comment: Do you need to know how many **specific** IDs in sequence you can get (like how many `5,4,1`s) or **any**-3-different-ids?

Comment: @izk Its a conceptual or algorithmic question - I'm looking for help on how go about it.

Comment: @u_mulder [5,4,1] was just an example

Comment: @dragoste the maximum number of 3 different ids I can get from to the list of ids in the array.

Comment: I've marked the key words in my question and you again missed it in your answer. Are you looking for **specific** set of IDs, or **any** set of IDs? It would be best if you provide excpected result for given example in your question.

Comment: @dragoste **any** set of ids as long as the values are unique e.g. [5,4,1], [3,2,1], [5,4,3] - however the crucial bit for me is how many sets of different ids I can get from one list, as that determines how many times I can apply the offer to the customer's basket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you can follow:

```
$basket = array(5, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 5);
$length = 3; //unique set size

function getSetCount($basket, $length) {
    $counts = array_count_values($basket); //count of each ID
    $totalCount = count($basket); //count of all elements

    //maximum amount of sets
    $max = floor($totalCount / $length);

    //since every ID can be only once in a set, it all above $max occurences won't be able to fit any set.
    $reducedCounts = array_map(function ($el) use ($max) {
        return min($el, $max);
    }, $counts);

    //final result is "all elements that should fit in sets / size of set
    return floor(array_sum($reducedCounts) / $length);
}
```

If you would like to print them:

```
function printSets($basket, $length) {
    $counts = array_count_values($basket); //count of each ID

    while(!empty($counts)) {
        arsort($counts);//reverse sort with keeping the keys
        $set = array_slice(array_keys($counts),0,$length); //get the set
        echo implode(',', $set) . '<br/>';
        foreach($set as $id) { //reduce counts
            $counts[$id]--;
        }
        $counts = array_filter($counts); //clean zeros
    }
}
```

The code above may not handle proparly some edge cases. But this is the idea.

Basically [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.array-count-values.php) counts values' occurences and returns an array of `value => count` pairs. Then its easy to manipulate this data.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know the maximum number of times I can get a set of 3 unique values from the array, so I can work out how many times to apply the offer to the basket.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - I've applied it out and ran a few tests and so far it seems very good. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly:

```
function getChunksCount($products)
{   
    // get unique ids
    $uniqueProducts = array_unique($products);

    // count unique ids
    $count = count($uniqueProducts);

    // let's get the number of chucks available
    $chunkSize = 3;

    // round to the floor
    return floor($count / $chunkSize);
}
```

No complex logic or processing at all. Next time try to write down what exactly needs to be done in what order, and the solution might become pretty obvious :)

Comment: Sorry, I think you've misunderstood what I require. I need to know the maximum number of times I can get a set of 3 unique values from the array, so I can work out how many times to apply the offer to the basket.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `array_unique` and `array_slice`.

```
$arr = [5, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 5];

$new_arr = array_slice(array_unique($arr), 0, 3);
print_r($new_arr); //Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 4 [2] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

```
<?php `$array = array(5, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 5); $vals = array_count_values($array); echo 'No. of NON Duplicate Items: '.count($vals).'<br><br>'; print_r($vals);`?>
```

Output is -Array ( [5] => 4 [4] => 2 [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 2 )